Disaggregation algorithm that maintains mass balance?
I am working with monthly timeseries data that I need to represent as daily data. I am looking for a disaggregation algorithm or Python/R package where:

Daily values smoothly increase from one month to the next and there is no end of month "stair-step"
Mass balance is preserved (ie the sum of the daily values equals the monthly total)
Has different options for monthly data slopes (use another time series, linear, constant)

I expect this will be some kind of optimization-driven function since simple "splining" can make the end of month data smoothly transition into the next month, but at the expense of the monthly total.
